# How to configure a Servlet to HazelCast route using Camel

Tags: apache-camel, hazelcast

I want to build a route something like

```
<route>
  <from uri="servlet:///user?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
  <to uri="direct:put"/>
</route>

<route>
<from uri="direct:put"/>
<setHeader headerName="CamelHazelcastOperationType">
<constant>put</constant>
</setHeader>
<to uri="hazelcast:map:foo"/>
</route>
```

ie everything that matches POST:/user/{cachename}/{key1} should take the key1 as key and place the payload under key:key1 to map:{cachename}.

Same thing for

GET:/user/{cachename}/{key1} should take the {key1} as key and retrieve the payload under key1 from map:{cachename}.

Any Help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a number of Camel headers available from the incoming servlet, such as:

- CamelHttpMethod = GET
- CamelHttpPath = /user/{cachename}/{key1}

You could use code or an expression language to extract the information from there, a very basic example would be:

```
<setHeader headerName="cachename">
    <simple>${header.CamelHttpPath.split("/")[2]}</simple>
</setHeader>

<setHeader headerName="key1">
    <simple>${header.CamelHttpPath.split("/")[3]}</simple>
</setHeader>
```

Comment: Hi Bgossit that really helped but i got stuck with some serialization exception using hazelcastcomponent in camel can you see if you can put some light on the following post:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511545/camel-hazelcast-component-throwing-hazelcastserializationexception