# Camel HazelCast component throwing HazelcastSerializationException

Tags: apache-camel, hazelcast

I have the following route in Camel:

```
<route>
  <from uri="servlet:///user?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
   <setHeader headerName="cachename">
    <simple>${header.CamelHttpPath.split("/")[1]}</simple>
</setHeader>
<setHeader headerName="key1">
    <simple>${header.CamelHttpPath.split("/")[2]}</simple>
</setHeader>
  <to uri="direct:put"/>

</route>




<route>
    <from uri="direct:put" />
        <!-- If using version 2.8 and above set headerName to "CamelHazelcastOperationType" -->
    <setHeader headerName="CamelHazelcastOperationType">
        <constant>put</constant>
    </setHeader>
    <setHeader headerName="CamelHazelcastObjectId">
        <simple>${header.key1}</simple>
    </setHeader>
    <process ref="requestTimeProc"/>
    <to uri="hazelcast:map:default" />
</route>
```

And i am trying to put a string as value into the cache.

My HazelCast Configuration is :

```
<map name="default">

        <in-memory-format>OBJECT</in-memory-format>


        <backup-count>1</backup-count>

        <async-backup-count>0</async-backup-count>

        <time-to-live-seconds>0</time-to-live-seconds>

        <max-idle-seconds>0</max-idle-seconds>

        <eviction-policy>NONE</eviction-policy>

        <max-size policy="PER_NODE">0</max-size>

        <eviction-percentage>25</eviction-percentage>

        <merge-policy>com.hazelcast.map.merge.PassThroughMergePolicy</merge-policy>

    </map>
<serialization>
        <portable-version>0</portable-version>
    </serialization>
```

And i Am gettign the following exception:

```
2013-12-10 22:47:08,288 [tp-1763826860-0] ERROR DefaultErrorHandler            - Failed delivery for (MessageId: ID-DJD7W4R1-54721-1386740808850-0-1 on ExchangeId: ID-DJD7W4R1-54721-1386740808850-0-2). Exhausted after delivery attempt: 1 caught: com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: There is no suitable serializer for class org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache
com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: There is no suitable serializer for class org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toData(SerializationServiceImpl.java:172)[hazelcast-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.SerializationServiceImpl.toData(SerializationServiceImpl.java:157)[hazelcast-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at com.hazelcast.map.MapService.toData(MapService.java:666)[hazelcast-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at com.hazelcast.map.proxy.MapProxyImpl.put(MapProxyImpl.java:72)[hazelcast-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at com.hazelcast.map.proxy.MapProxyImpl.put(MapProxyImpl.java:60)[hazelcast-3.1.2.jar:3.1.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.hazelcast.map.HazelcastMapProducer.put(HazelcastMapProducer.java:136)[camel-hazelcast-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at org.apache.camel.component.hazelcast.map.HazelcastMapProducer.process(HazelcastMapProducer.java:71)[camel-hazelcast-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61)[camel-core-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:73)[camel-core-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
    at org.apache.camel.processor.SendProcessor$2.doInAsyncProducer(SendProcessor.java:122)[camel-core-2.11.2.jar:2.11.2]
```

Please let me know if i am missing anythign inthe configuration . I am using the default Hazelcast configuration provided int he Hazelcast jar. Any help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few comments:

I would not change the 'default' map. This means that any map in the system, which doesn't have an explicit configuration, will now use this configuration. So figure out which map is used and configure explicitly for that map.

```
 <map name="explicitName">
    <in-memory-format>OBJECT</in-memory-format>
    ....
</map>
```

About the exception:

com.hazelcast.nio.serialization.HazelcastSerializationException: There is no suitable serializer for class org.apache.camel.converter.stream.InputStreamCache

It means that the InputStreamCache is put in the map, but Hazelcast doesn't know how to conver it to a stream of bytes. You can plug in a serializer for this class, see the following blogpost how to do so:

http://blog.hazelcast.com/blog/2013/10/16/kryo-serializer/

The big question for me is: why are you trynig to put an InputStreamCache in a map? My gut feeling says that this class is not something you want to put in a distribured Hazelcast map at all.

Comment: Hi Pveentjer I am using Camel:HazelCast component to route the http request to hazelcast. The HazelcastProducer tries to add the request body to hazelcastmap which it is doing it as InputStreamCache

Comment: I'm not familiar with Camel, so perhaps it is best to ask somebody there to help you.

Comment: Hi pveentjer, adding a custom serializer worked thanks for your help but think that camel hazelcast component should have handled this.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Perhaps you can inform the Camel team so that the issue is resolved?